# requirement of 3 journal nodes in HA hadoop setup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability

I am quite new to hadoop. As i am setting up a hadoop namenode ha using qoroum journal manager, i am a bit confused on the requirements. The official documentations on apache site says

> Note: There must be at least 3 JournalNode daemons, since edit log modifications must be written to a majority of JNs.

what does this means? why do we need 3 journal-nodes instead of two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As in hadoop1 we can have only one Namenode per cluster if somehow this namenode become unavailable whole cluster will become unavailable  thus making it single point of failure.
2. To resolve this issue the obvious solution was to add more than one Namenode per cluster.
3. In haoop2 we can have two Namenode per cluster. At a time only one Namenode would be active and other would be in standby mode. To Make system HA both Namenode should be synchronised. To do so they introduced a concept journal nodes.
4. The purpose of this light weight demon is to sync every change in active Namenode to standby Namenodes.
5. Now what if this journal node would fail? .This would again became the same issue.journal node will become the Single point of failure. To avoid that they introduced a quorum concept like it was introduced in Zookeeper.

what Quorum means?

**Quorum** :- The literal meaning of quorum is 'minimum number of assembly/society member that must be present to make a meeting valid'.

On similar notes there must always be **more than half of the total journal nodes** to be healthy to keep everything running. e.g if you have 2 journal nodes in the system you would have to have to keep '**more than half**' i.e more than 1 which is 2 Journal nodes healthy to keep everything running. which means you can't take any journal node failures in this case. To avoid this you must have odd number of journal nodes (i.e 3,5,7). But minimum 3 so that we can bear journal node failures.

**I hope this helped**

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful.